# How can I add a persistent fullscreen image overlay?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm working on a React project, and I need to add a semi-transparent, fullscreen, persistent image overlay. How can I do this? Any positioning stuff that I've tried before (including `position: absolute` have resulted in other screwed-up formatting.

Here's where I'd need it to go:

```
    render() {  

        return (
            <div>
            {/* // overlay goes here */}
                <div className="App" ref={ div => this.appElement = div}>
                    <div className = "Panels" ref={ div => this.panelElement = div}>
                        {this.instantiatePanels()[this.state.currentDisplayedIndex]}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-newton-hfen3?file=/index.html)? I've used `position: fixed` so it covers the entire scrolling area.